# Once istio injection enabled POD not able to connect external endpoints

Tags: istio

Once istio injection enabled POD not able to connect external endpoints. Based on document it suggested to follow service entry (similar to this [Pod cannot curl external website after adding istio egress gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52883719/pod-cannot-curl-external-website-after-adding-istio-egress-gateway)). But my case I have N number of endpoints.. and dont have ip list for those endpoints

Is there better way to address this issue without service entry.

Answer (score 1):

The options for controlling traffic to external endpoints are described here: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/. It is either a [ServiceEntry](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#configuring-istio-external-services), or [direct access](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#calling-external-services-directly).

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to control the outbound you can configure istio to not block outgoing traffic by issuing the following command:

helm install install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.loadBalancerIP="x.x.x.x" --set global.proxy.includeIPRanges="0.0.0.0"

this will enable all outbound traffic to by pass the egressgateway